# Yocto gitlab CI job sometimes causes touch gives Operation not permitted

Tags: yocto, gitlab-ci-runner, seccomp

I run Yocto builds in gitlab CI, and sometimes I get this kind of error:

```
touch: setting times of '/builds/linux-bsp/distro/yocto/build/tmp-glibc/work/pcm62-oe-linux/pil-rootfs/1.0-r0/rootfs/usr/share/common-licenses/deif-kernel-module-lpddr4-6.5.2-rt8-00061-ga5ee5b82d6e5/GPL-2.0-only': Operation not permitted
touch: setting times of '/builds/linux-bsp/distro/yocto/build/tmp-glibc/work/pcm62-oe-linux/pil-rootfs/1.0-r0/rootfs/usr/share/common-licenses/generic_NCSA': Operation not permitted
WARNING: /builds/linux-bsp/distro/yocto/build/tmp-glibc/work/pcm62-oe-linux/pil-rootfs/1.0-r0/temp/run.reproducible_final_image_task.247046:155 exit 123 from 'xargs -0 touch -h --date=@$REPRODUCIBLE_TIMESTAMP_ROOTFS'
```

Whenever it happens I just need to do a rerun of the job.

Note that the error is: "Operation not permitted" not "permission denied".
This typically means, that it is seccomp which blocks an operation. Not something with file permissions!

However I have totally disabled seccomp in the runner!

```
security_opt = ["seccomp:unconfined"]
```

**Why do I get this error, what causes this kind of error?**

For the Yocto audience, there is two things which always is involved when I see this error:

- It is doing this operation: touch -h
  --date=@$REPRODUCIBLE_TIMESTAMP_ROOTFS'
- And it is always on a licence file!

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 with a 5.15 kernel on the runner.

Comment: The only reason I'm not voting to close in favour of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77412512/gitlab-runner-operation-not-permitted) on this is because the close vote UI says "This question has been asked before and ***already has an answer***.". I'm pretty sure you shouldn't do this though. Perhaps close your old question?

Comment: Thanks, I deleted the old question. I actually forgot about it.